# Need help regarding random password generator: Urgent

Tags: algorithms, randomness

I had generated a random password from a website which unfortunately has put me into trouble.

The password contains 26 characters which includes alphabets, numbers and special characters. My trouble started when it was found that among the 26 characters there was a 4 letter Malayalam word (spelled in English) which is interpreted to be abusive, followed by an exclamation mark and then again followed by 3 alphabets which unfortunately consists of the initials of the person to whom I had sent the password.

How can I make others believe that this can be auto generated using a random password/string generator algorithm?

I request those people who are acquainted with such algorithms to please help me in this regard. Those who can help me may please reply at the earliest.

Comment: Without knowing the algorithm, it would be impossible.

Comment: Would you be able to help if I gave you the details of the website from which it was generated?

Comment: Not really. Also, this site isn't really a good fit for anything urgent. We prefer questions the stay for posterity, and work at our own pace.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no way to do this. First, the website generating the password would need to be open source, or at least publish what algorithm they use. Supposing they do that, then we would need to know the "inputs" to the algorithm. That would depend on their source of randomness: it might be the microsecond that your query was submitted, or it might be random mouse movements, or it might be random atmospheric data. It's also possible that the website uses some "secret salt" in addition to the randomness source, so that their results can't be replicated from the randomness alone.

Really, we have two situations. Either the password can't be recovered/explained, because the website is using proper security to make sure that your password is secret. Or, you can fully recreate the inputs to the algorithm, in which case someone else could, meaning that your password isn't very secure.

There is a third possibility, which is that this website isn't legitimate, and it's deliberately returning things with Malay profanity. I'd try generating another password to see. But in all likelihood you're just terribly unlucky.